# React keep data attribute

Tags: reactjs, variables, methods

I have to do a 'simple' task. It is actually simple if you know the react framework or have any Javascripts knowledge in particular but my Javascript knowledge is pretty terible so I am really stuck now.

What I am trying to achieve is, I have a button 'terminate' in a table (so several rows). When I click the button, I want the console log to throw me the transactionID of that row. But I really cannot get it to work. This is what I have currently:

**I have a class with in it several methods, of one is a 5 sec auto refresh function:**

```
var ExceptionalCases = React.createClass({
```

**I created this method:**

```
TerminateCase: function(e) { 
  e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
    }, function() {   
        var transactionID = this.refs.transid.target.getAttribute("data-transid");
        console.log('button clicked' + transactionID);
    }.bind(this));
```

},

**And this is the button (located in the render):**

```
<input type="button" name="TerminateCase" value={_('Terminate')} style={{width: '110px'}}
   onClick={this.TerminateCase} ref="transid" data-transid={entry.transactionId}/>
```

This is the error I get:
TypeError: this.refs.transid.target is undefined

I am clueless, I searched alot and tried many different approaches but I am really stuck now. I hope that someone can help me ;-(

Comment: try `e.target` instead of `this.refs.transid.target`

Comment: Try constructing the function you pass to `onClick` in a way that it refers to the value you use in render time, like `onClick={() => this.TerminateCase(entry.transactionId)}`. Remember that React reflects data into UI, and whenever you want to go in the opposite direction (take data from DOM node), think if it's worth it first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
TerminateCase: function(e) { 
  e.preventDefault();
  var transactionID = e.currentTarget.getAttribute("data-transid");
  console.log('button clicked' + transactionID);
}
```

Comment: In React, you have data first, so you rarely need to refer to DOM element from an instance of Event. By time the component is rendered, the value of `data-transid` is known it's the value of `entry.transactionId`. That should be the reference, not DOM attribute.